# Facebook Likes on pages within a page tab app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm building a page tab app on Facebook that allows users to create and display their own entries, and I want to be able to have a share and a like button specific to each entry.

I'm using the app_data parameter to pass the path to the page within the app, and it works perfectly with the share button - a user can share their entry to their wall, and that share links back to the appropriate page.

However, when I try to do the same thing with Likes, it instead shows the total likes for the page the page tab is a child of. Has anyone had a similar problem or could point me in the right direction to sorting it out?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t like specific page tab contents – Facebook will count all likes for the Facebook page, no matter what app ID and possibly app_data the URL contains.

You could however like your own URLs that are loaded inside the page tab frame – and have them redirect to themselves embedded into the iframe with JavaScript if a real user is visiting them.

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying out that exact thing - it works, the counter shows the correct amount of likes, but bizarrely the Like doesn't show up on my Facebook profile, any idea why? I realise this is now an offshoot of the original question, I'm not sure on the etiquette involved in this situation...